# Best way of checking Null in C# 4.0

Tags: linq, datetime, c#-4.0

I was checking null like below for `modifiedDate`, it was working fine in **4.5** but as soon as my code deployed in **C# 4.0** it is not working. What is the best way of handling below condition in **4.0** ?

```
modifiedDate = b?.last_modified?[0] ?? DateTime.Now,

var searchedDataList = objJson.response.docs.Select(b =>
                new finalOutput
                {
                    modifiedDate = b?.last_modified?[0] ?? DateTime.Now,               
                    Size = b.stream_size[0]
                }).ToList<finalOutput>();

 public Nullable<DateTime> modifiedDate { get; set; }
```

I tried modifying like this but it does not work -

```
 modifiedDate = b.last_modified[0] ?? DateTime.Now
```

Comment: What is `last_modified`?

Comment: public List<Nullable<DateTime>> last_modified { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using below -

```
modifiedDate = b!= null && b.last_modified != null && 
b.last_modified[0] != null ? b.last_modified[0].Value : DateTime.Now
```